# json php + javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Preciso do seguinte: pego oq foi digitado no input com o código abaixo e passo para a url: http://bonusdogeronimo.com.br/rtv/indez.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").submit(function(e){
  if(!$("form").hasClass("valid")){
    $("form").addClass("loading");
    e.preventDefault();

    //
    $.post("http://bonusdogeronimo.com.br/rtv/indez.php", {
      email : $("form #email").val()
    }, function(result){
      var resultParse = JSON.parse(result);
      if(resultParse.status == "valid"){
        $("form").addClass("valid");
        $("form").submit();
      }else{
        alert("Parece que você digitou um e-mail errado!");
        $("form").removeClass("valid");
      }
      $("form").removeClass("loading");
    });
  }
});
});
</script>
```

No meu Index.php eu tenho esse código ondem pego o resultado do json passando email e api por GET

```
<?php
//$email = 'andre.mariano@ssmsn.com';
$apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$email = $_GET['email'];



// Inicia o cURL acessando uma URL
$cURL = curl_init("https://bpi.briteverify.com/emails.json?address=" . 
$email . '&apikey=' . $apikey);
// Define a opção que diz que você quer receber o resultado encontrado
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Executa a consulta, conectando-se ao site e salvando o resultado na 
variável $resultado
$resultado = curl_exec($cURL);
$json = json_decode($resultado, true); 
// Encerra a conexão com o site
curl_close($cURL);

//print $resultado;
print '<br>';

    echo 'E-mail: ' . $json['status'];

     print '<br>';



  ?>
```

até aqui tudo funciona, porém não consigo receber de volta no meu primeiro código a resposta da api, preciso retornar ao primeiro script o resultado de $json['status']; se é valid ou invalid, assim entrou no IF do primeiro script

```
if(resultParse.status == "valid"){
        $("form").addClass("valid");
        $("form").submit();
      }else{
        alert("Parece que você digitou um e-mail errado!");
        $("form").removeClass("valid");
```

Essa URL aqui --> http://egratitude.com.br/src/sources/avulsos/returnpath.php faz exatamente oq eu preciso, porém não consigo ver como o cara fez, pois ao acessar essa url ele já trás o resultado do json.

Comment: Como está funcionando se você está enviando com `$.post` e no PHP você está pegando via `$_GET`..... qual mágica você fez? kkkk

Comment: Remove todos os `print` no seu PHP e no echo coloque `echo json_encode(array('status'=>$json['status']));` ou dê direto um echo em `$json`.

Answer (score 1):

No envio eu sugiro já colocar o retorno em JSON

```
$.post("http://bonusdogeronimo.com.br/rtv/indez.php", {
      email : $("form #email").val()
    }, function(result){
      if(result.status == "valid"){
        $("form").addClass("valid");
        $("form").submit();
      }else{
        alert("Parece que você digitou um e-mail errado!");
        $("form").removeClass("valid");
      }
      $("form").removeClass("loading");
    },'json'); // <---- Adição da forma de retorno
```

No seu PHP, corrigir a forma de recebimento da informação do e-mail

```
<?php
//$email = 'andre.mariano@ssmsn.com';
$apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$email = $_POST['email']; // <---- Correção
```

No seu retorno, remover os `print` e colocar o retorno no `echo`

```
//print $resultado;
echo json_encode(array('status'=>$json['status']));
```

Ou dar direto um echo na variável `$json`

```
//print $resultado;
echo $json;
```